# NUXT JS Interceptor for 404 or any errors with error method not working

Tags: vue.js, axios, vue-router, nuxt.js

#### Version

[v5.8.0](https://github.com/axios-module/releases/tag/v5.8.0)

#### Reproduction link

https://github.com/msonowal/nuxt-bug-reproduce-link

#### Steps to reproduce

add this in 
`plugins` dir make file name it  `axios.js`

and add the link in nuxt config plugins array 
visit any route whose axios calls are 404

axios.js  file content below

```
export default function({ $axios, error }) {
  $axios.onError((responseError) => {
    if (responseError.response.status === 404) {
      error({ statusCode: 404, message: 'Post not found from interceptor' })
    }
  })
}
```

#### What is expected ?

show the error response with 404 code as defined in the nuxt app
Post not found from interceptor

but

not redirect to 301

#### What is actually happening?

it is showing default nuxt error

**NuxtServerError**
`Request failed with status code 404`

<sub>*This bug report is available on [Nuxt](https://cmty.app/nuxt) community ([#c305](https://cmty.app/nuxt/axios-module/issues/c305))*</sub>

Comment: axios doesn't handle nuxt routing errors

Comment: for best practice catch the error and return to error page

Comment: @sidheart Thats what I have custom error page setup to handle these errors form nuxt so I want to automate the axios fails to use that same view and make the core SOLID and DRY

Comment: @msonowal before i thought this plugins style will works fine. but no i was wrong i think this is bug or this feature not added yet. be clear check my answer how i managed 404 error

Comment: Add `throw responseError` after if ?

Answer (score 2):

This seem to work for me

_.vue

```
async asyncData(context) {
  ...
  try {
    const response = await context.$axios(options);
    ...          
  } catch (error) {
    context.error({ statusCode: 404, message: 'Page not found' });
  }
}
```

error.vue

```
<template>
  <h1>{{ error.message }}</h1>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    head() {
      return {
        title: `${this.statusCode} | ${this.message}`,
      }
    },
    props: {
      error: {
        type: Object,
        default: null
      }
    },
    computed: {
      statusCode() {
        return (this.error && this.error.statusCode) || 500;
      },
      message() {
        return this.error.message;
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the way you can handle error 404

```
asyncData({ $axios, params, error }) {
    return $axios
      .get(`/user/${params.profile}`)
      .then(res => {
        return { user: res.data.data };
      })
      .catch(e => {
        error({ statusCode: 404, message: 'Page not found' });
      });
  },
```